# What are reason for thread interrupt if main thread never calls thread.interrupt()?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt-handling

So whenever we are making a blocking call like thread.sleep(), we handle the checked interrupted exception. I wanted to know what can be the various reasons that could indeed interrupt the sleeping thread if we are not explicitly calling thread.interrupt()?

I googled and found this https://codepumpkin.com/interruptedexception-java-multithreading/. The blog says that the thread interruption can occur if application shutdown happens but I think application shutdown would explicitly kill the thread afterwards even if we don't handle the exception.

Comment: If the thread is part of an `ExecutorService` and it's currently executing a task while another thread calls `cancel(true)` on the `Future`, the thread will be interrupted.

Comment: I know this is pretty crude, but when I "grep" the Java code in the Java 8 codebase, I get 130 matches for `interrupt()` excluding test cases.   Conclusion: there are lots of possible reasons.  And that ignores possible interrupts coming from native code, 3rd-party libraries and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the info  @Slaw!, but I need to know what can be the "sources" apart from code itself, which can interrupt the threads. Actually I wanted to know why do I need to "handle" interrupted action when no where in my code thread.cancel or interrupt is been called. 
PS: By handling the exception I mean doing something, If the case is never occuring can't I simply leave the catch block empty?

Comment: "Conclusion: there are lots of possible reasons" @Stephen C can you list some of the reasons?

Comment: @Coderdoit - You could do that yourself by doing what I just did: 1) download the source code, 2) search for occurrences by running `find . -name \*.java | xargs grep "interrupt()" | grep -v test`, 3) examine each file with a "hit".

Comment: Alternatively ... just handle the `InterruptedException` appropriately on the assumption that you will get interrupts, and if they are not expected they should not be squashed.

Comment: When you compile a class, the compiler has no way of knowing whether that class eventually will be used in a thread that will be interrupted or not. Therefore, it must _assume_ that the class _could_ be used in a thread that will be interrupted.